# OpenLayers change:rotation not called

Tags: javascript, openlayers, events, ol-cesium, typescript

I am using ol-cesium and I want to receive an event when the map is rotated. So my approach is to use the `change:rotation` event of the `ol.Map`, but it is never called.

```
this.map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            tileLayer
        ],
        controls: [],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.372542, 47.426919]),
            zoom: 12,
            minZoom: 12
        }),
    });

    this.map.getView().on('change:rotation', () => {
        console.log("fired");
    });
```

I am also using typescript but this shouldn't be the problem. My development browser is Google Chrome.

Comment: which version of OL do you use? if it's latest one, it seems the error is caused with ol-cesium.

Comment: I am using OL 4.3.2. Ok so there would be no better solution to just poll the rotation on `this.mapView.map.on('movestart', () => {})`?